# How to cut out numbers from an image dynamically?

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing

i've got to this stage:
[image: picture of img]

where i can find the numbers in the above image but i need to cut them out so i can retain the order etc. but the as the number increases the spacing changes and the position of the number?

so i think it should be a find a white PX the continue until it find a solid black col and then use the points to do a simple cut any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be this:

1. Find the first upmost horizontal line which contains white pixels
2. From that line find the first horizontal line which contains only black pixels

Those two lines are your upper and lower borders.

Between this borders proceed like this:

1. Find the first most left vertical line which contains white pixels
2. From that line find the last vertical line which contains only black pixels and which comes directly after a line with white pixels.

Those two lines are your left and right borders.

The steps to separate single numbers can be performed analogously.

If you need to identify which numbers are in your picture, I recommend using specialized computer vision libraries.

Some VB.net pseudo code to get you going:

```
Sub FindTopBorder(image As MyImage) As Integer
  For y = 0 to image.Height - 1
    For x = 0 to image.Width - 1
      Dim pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y)
      If ('Check if pixel is white here with RGB or Color') Then
        Return y
      End If
    Next
  Next
  ' Just in case there are no white pixels or use an exception instead
  Return -1
End Sub
```

Comment: could you knock a little code togeather to do just one of the sides as i have no idea how to start it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would start looking into Connected component segmentation. You find a pixel which is within a character (number). Then run the connected component algorithm which finds all connected pixels under specific set of rules (e.g. slight deviation in color, stop at hard borders etc).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

If you can use libraries, I'm sure OpenCV or similar libraries support this out of the box.

//edit
I see you need VB.net. Probably it is easiest to port some algorithm to VB or create one yourself.

See e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336915/Connected-Component-Labeling-Algorithm

> **What to expect**
>
> *Input*
>
> An image containing two shapes:
>
> *Output*
>
> Now each is separated into single images.